# Why do I have to re-login everytime with this authentication process

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

I set-up an ASP.Net Core 3.0 webserver with the following configuration in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            }
        )
        .AddInMemoryCaching()
        .AddClientStore<InMemoryClientStore>()
        .AddResourceStore<InMemoryResourcesStore>();

        services.AddAuthentication();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseFileServer();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

You can see that I set the cookie lifetime to 30 days.

and here is the code that is run when I sign-in with a username/password:

```
    [HttpGet("Signin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<AccountResponse>> Signin([FromQuery]string email, [FromQuery]string password)
    {
        var (account, status) = accountRepository.AuthenticateAccount(email, password);
        if (status == AccountRepository.AuthenticateAccountStatusEnum.InvalidEmailPassword)
            return new ResponseBuilder<AccountResponse>().WithError("Invalid email/password").Build();
        else if (status == AccountRepository.AuthenticateAccountStatusEnum.AccountExternalProvider)
            return new ResponseBuilder<AccountResponse>().WithError("This email is not associated with a local account.").Build();
        else if (account.Status == AccountStatusEnum.WaitingForVerificationCode)
            return new ResponseBuilder<AccountResponse>(Mapper.Map<AccountResponse>(account))
                .WithMessage("This email address is still not verified.")
                .Build();
        else
            return await CompleteLogin(account);
    }

    private async Task<AccountResponse> CompleteLogin(AccountModel account)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(account.Email, account.Email, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30) });

        return Mapper.Map<AccountResponse>(account).WithAuthenticated();
    }
```

You can see that I set again the expiration to 30 days and `IsPersistent` to true.

All of this works well. If I login and close the browser and re-open it, it is still authenticated.

**The only thing wrong is that if I login and let time pass, say a night, I refresh the page and am not authenticated anymore.**

What am I missing? I want the user to stay authenticated for long time (even if he closes the browser, reboots, etc.).

### Edit:

Here is the cookie that I see from the browser:

[image]

It looks okay...Notice that this cookie information comes from a browser session that is "Signed-out" (strangely?)

Comment: This ultimately results in a cookie being set - can you check the details of said cookie to ensure it looks correct?

Comment: @mackie good point, see my edit

Comment: That content looks suspiciously short - what do they look like after you'd signed in?

Comment: @mackie oh I think it's just a dialog UI thing, the `Content` string doesn't show fully. Here is what I got after signing-in: `CfDJ8AtN3KK4ix9LmAwPHgRSnkncLSU-l2ZFpKH3OwjvA1yLD5kRUX-2b1RKcTo8kVntSq7o-Xez408pMMF8vjZ7yhy54Y9BhTwtrcmYcEDSEt5R-YF5dleC1tAYMg0j-WeK5U5j3Ni_pkYf9WlY5nzIa6sq-9m42kkd...[TRUNCATED]....yaw97y6211sBTwISbDCE8PO-JybVwG4XFMPboWyG9npqqLbBh-JK6qfJ15yEeXcrCKMMRvsZ7AEOSXP0xBe3Qz48qllfV59WP82ui-76posFhX1hmT6I4TyMReZ6CErAsPhhaqNe-FySR7lnoXZuwqTBuWqZN0TIiR2Dij7N306AVCGSvfvJc41l1Ohcuz3OpcihqAg1gWdyIn5Ht578FAUmS4I4b8`, it was probably as long as that before signing-in

Comment: @mackie when I click Sign-out and check the cookie value, the content is a completely empty string

Comment: is the cookie still set to a value after refreshing the page after a night?